# How can we resolve error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\lib\ARMV4I\retail\certmod.lib'

Tags: windows-ce

I am getting following error after trying to build WinCE 6 OS image for ARM V4. After a search online roll-ups for ARMv4 is installed , still facing the issue.
Implemented suggestions 
  https://guruce.com/blogpost/windows-embedded-qfes-updates
  http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/3115

```
    SysgenMake  /NOLOGO C:\Novus\dev01\OS\WinCE_6.0\OSDesigns\AtlasXL\Wince600\AtlasXL_ARMV4I\cesysgen\oak\target\ARMV4I\retail\certmod.dll
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\lib\ARMV4I\retail\certmod.lib'
Stop.
makefile.def: Invoked with predefined settings:
TARGETNAME: certmod
TARGETTYPE: DYNLINK
RELEASETYPE: OAK
TARGETLIBS: C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\lib\ARMV4I\retail\certmod.lib C:\Novus\dev01\OS\WinCE_6.0\OSDesigns\AtlasXL\Wince600\AtlasXL_ARMV4I\cesysgen\sdk\lib\ARMV4I\retail\crypt32.lib C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\lib\ARMV4I\retail\evgen.lib C:\Novus\dev01\OS\WinCE_6.0\OSDesigns\AtlasXL\Wince600\AtlasXL_ARMV4I\cesysgen\sdk\lib\ARMV4I\retail\coredll.lib
SOURCELIBS: 
DEFFILE: C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\lib\ARMV4I\retail\certmod.def
EXEENTRY: mainWCRTStartup
DLLENTRY: _DllMainCRTStartup
makefile.def: Including C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\misc\Sources.default
makefile.def: BUILDROOT is C:\WINCE600\public\common\cesysgen
makefile.def: Including C:\WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\CESYSGEN\sources
makefile.def: Including C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\misc\Sources.CE
Directory: C:\WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\CESYSGEN
TARGETNAME: certmod
makefile.def: Including C:\WINCE600\public\common\oak\misc\sources.ReleaseType_OAK

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'SysgenMake' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Help me out in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this error is a result of infamous BUILD AND SYSGEN option available with WEC6 build commands, see https://guruce.com/blogpost/how-to-remove-the-demonic-build-and-sysgen-commands-from-platform-builder-for-windows-embed for details.

Please reinstall platform builder and NEVER EVER DO A BUILD AND SYSGEN.

Comment: To find out the underlying problem it will be useful to build `C:/WINCE600/PUBLIC/common/oak/drivers/security` node in the platform builder